# Raising a Magpie

Tags: training, birds, growing

a few weeks ago I found a baby magpie, that have fallen of its nest, and has lost its parents.

I recovered it and raised it. Now it is strong and healthy, has grown up and it looks to me pretty mature. The last few days it can even fly very well (I believe perfectly...). It is not in a cage, but in a room, it is very energetic and has very good relationship with humans.

The first days I fed it in the mouth, like its parents would do. The problem is that now that it has grown up it still asks for food from me, and it does not eat on its own. This is problematic for both of us.

How can I train it to be independent, feed on its own, and thus eventually free it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to worry--young magpies leave the nest before they are fully independent. (This is a survival mechanism. The longer they stay in a single place, the more likely that a predator will find them in that place.) Parents continue to feed the babies for several weeks after fledging. Your baby magpie will start eating on its own when it is ready. Be sure to leave its favorite treats out where it can find them, and it will start to take them on its own.

You did great work raising the baby! You're almost at the finish line. The baby will tell you when it's ready.

Tom G.